# How are equation (6) deduced?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Im recently reading a paper and there are a lot of points that I dont understand.

[https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~todorov/papers/TassaICRA14.pdf](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Etodorov/papers/TassaICRA14.pdf)

[image]

I think equation (5b) is deduced by

[image]

But after getting equation (5b), I have zero ideas how equation (6) are deduced.

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10913/how-are-equation-6-deduced